# limited record accessing using SQL

Tags: sql

How can I get limited no.of records from database into a web page using SQL query?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you're not giving any info to help you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The SQL standard for that is `fetch first x rows only`. See e.g. here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT

Answer (score -1):

How to limit the number of result rows depends on the database software you are using; see the appropriate documentation. Microsoft products allow this via the keyword `TOP`, like so:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    *
FROM
    table_name;
```

MySQL, for instance, use `LIMIT` instead:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
LIMIT
    10;
```

In Oracle Database, use `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    ROWNUM <= 10;
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: You are absolutely right, @a_horse_with_no_name - how could I miss this. Edited my answer, thank you!